# Shut down when asked without terminal help

Tags: 11.10, shutdown

My system has Ubuntu 11.10, and it will not shut down when asked to. It will reboot to the sign-in page. I have been using `sudo shutdown -h now` to shut down, but is it any way to put this into the program so ask to shutdown it will without going to terminal?

Answer (score 1):

The shutdown and reboot options can only be used by a non-privileged user if they are the only user logged in to the system.  Chances are that your system thinks that there is another user on the system.

You can get a list of the active sessions using the `ck-list-sessions` command:

```
$ ck-list-sessions 
Session2:
    unix-user = '1000'
    realname = 'James Henstridge'
    seat = 'Seat1'
    session-type = ''
    active = TRUE
    x11-display = ':0'
    x11-display-device = '/dev/tty7'
    display-device = ''
    remote-host-name = ''
    is-local = TRUE
    on-since = '2012-04-05T23:36:58.278097Z'
    login-session-id = '1234567890'
```

If you see more than one session listed, then this is the reason why the shutdown and reboot options fail and you get returned to the login screen instead.

I once had a problem where ConsoleKit believed that one of the daemons running on the system represented a user session and causing this problem, so that could be your problem.

Alternatively, if you've logged in multiple times consider logging out of your other sessions before trying to use the shutdown or reboot options.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason makes your Ubuntu not shutdown with buttons?

Try repairing your Desktop Env. from software center. This may help, may be.